# Swiper version 8.2.2 can't change the button colors [React]

Tags: reactjs, swiper.js

I am using swiper v 8.2.2 although its working but I wanted to change the color of slider's button right now its blue but want to change to orange. I even checked all the files, couldn't figure out the which file is directly impacting.

Hope you dont mind the novice question. Looking for answer
thanks

Comment: Well For now I override those value in the other css file. but still want to see where are the original values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add this to swiper component and change #fff to whatever color you want

```
style={{
    "--swiper-pagination-color": "#fff",
    "--swiper-navigation-color": "#fff",
  }}
```